# Jsoup: Extracting a number in parenthesis outside an element?

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

New to Jsoup. I am trying to retrieve the number "84" from the code below:

```
<a id="utilAllProd" class="utilAllProdAct" href="javascript:;"><span class="utilNumbProd">    (84)</span></a>
```

I am used to extracting information based on attribute names, ie. finding all elements with a certain tag from the Document, then calling .attr(attribute) on the element, but how could I access this number in parenthesis?

EDIT: What about retrieving the number 84 from the following?

```
<div id="botUtilBar" class="utilityBar clearfix">


    <div id="nmbProdItems" class="utilFltLft">
        <span>
        Items&nbsp;&nbsp;
                1-25
                </strong>&nbsp;of&nbsp;84   
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="itemsPerPage2" class="utilFltLft">
        <select id="viewItems"">
```

Comment: It looks like it is included in the span.  Can you just use a class selector for `utilNumbProd ` then strip the parenthesis?   I would need to see a larger data set to know for sure.

Comment: @buzzsawddog Thanks, buzzsawddog, that worked!

Also, would you know what to do with a code like this?

    <span>
      Items&nbsp;&nbsp;
        1-25
        </strong>&nbsp;of&nbsp;84 
      </span>

still trying to retrieve the number 84

Comment: Can you provide a slightly larger dataset?

Comment: @buzzsawddog Ok, I provided some more code in my original question so it's more readable. Does that work? (I omitted the beginning of the "strong" tag because that was 200 lines of code above)

Comment: The tags look mismatched :-s  See that closing `</strong>`  where does that open?  Walking through it in my head, grab `nmbProdItems` then the `<span>` inside.  If it always sets the page up the same look for the number after the `&nbsp`.  Not a well formed page :-(

Comment: Confirmed very dirty html indeed http://bit.ly/16B3N6C shows a similar code sample to what you have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a css selector looking for `utilNumbProd` then strip the parenthesis in java.